# Android Studio - How to get rid of duplicate packages of different case lettering?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am facing a problem where after naming packages with capital letters by mistake, I renamed them to be lowercase. The result is that there are multiple packages of the same name ("View" and "view"
) and I cannot get rid of the packages with uppercase.

I tried starting a new project and adding the old files in, and checked each class's package name. All are named correctly in lowercase, but Android studio insists that there is also a package in uppercase with the same files.

What could be the cause of the problem? Is it Git or some kind of caching issue?

[image: Multiple packages shown in Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

You most likely see "Android"view on your left side of the screen shot. This is not reflecting filesystem strucuture (for that switch to" Project Files") but rather is built based in source code contents. This means that you should check all the source files and see what package names are there, and correct that. Then invalidate Android Studio cache (may not be needed though) and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press double shift and search with the package name in the files tab and you will find all the folders with the package name regardless of case .

[image: panel]